# How to add Blazor Webassembly to the Identity Area of an existing ASP.NET Core web app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, blazor, webassembly

I have an ASP Razor page web app.
I want to add a **Blazor component** to my project.
It ***works*** when I put this line in the **index.cshtml**

```
<component type="typeof(CountComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

But when I add the component to a **cshtml** file in **Identity Area**

**ProjectMainFolder\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\ManageUsers.cshtml**

It does not works.
[image]

This is my StartUp.cs

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<AmarbarHub>("/AmarbarHub");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});
```

And This

```
services.AddServerSideBlazor(o => o.DetailedErrors = true);

services.AddControllersWithViews()
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

services.AddRazorPages()
.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Admin", "/");
});

services.AddSignalR();
```

Also I've added this line before  ends

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

I've searched and tried a lote with no sucess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a test in my side but I didn't reproduce your issue as the Counter component could loaded and worked well in both index.cshtml and manageusers.cshtml. I'm afraid you could follow [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#render-components-from-a-page-or-view) to check if you missed something eles.

Firstly, although you add webassembly tag for your question, but I noticed you had added `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` so that I'm afraid you are not trying to add wsam component.

So my test steps is:

1.create Counter.razor in Shared folder

2.put the component into index.html by tag helper `<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />`  along with the `@using projectname.Pages.Shared` clause.

3. add `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();` in Program.cs, and add `app.MapBlazorHub();` behind `app.MapRazorPages();`. I also test with your `app.UseEndpoints` which worked as well.
4. in `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, add `<base href="~/" />` in `<head>` tag, and add `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` immediately before `@await RenderSectionAsync(...)` .

With Steps above, I can see the counter component loaded in the page, but when clicking the button, it didn't work. Looks like the component becomes noninteractive. I found that's due to missing adding `_Import.razor` in the root folder of the project. So we need step 5.

5. Add `_Import.razor` to the root folder of the project.

   @using System.Net.Http

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization

   @using Microsoft.JSInterop

   @using WebAppDefIdentity//project name here

And test result:

[image]

Then I found that we don't have default `ManageUsers.cshtml` from scaffold, so I create this page manually and also test it within another page in Identity Area.

```
@page
@using WebAppDefIdentity.Pages.Shared

<div>this is manage user page</div>

<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear @Tiny_Wang you are so kind, you've spent a lote of time to solve my problem, when I've added   <base href="~/" /> to my layout it started working what does it do ? and my next question is that if I want add WASM I dont need to add  this ? <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

Comment: @Arash.Zandi Hi, thanks a lot for your kind reply, we have a sentence in the document for the href: `The href value (the app base path) in the preceding example assumes that the app resides at the root URL path (/). If the app is a sub-application, follow the guidance in the App base path section of the Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor article.`

Comment: and if we are handling blazor wsam scenario, we should have `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>` instead. [The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly) also contain the option for wsam.

Comment: Dear @TinyWang Your comments was extremely helpful, I appreciate you.